# Deploying CXF JAX-WS Web Service in Glassfish but not in JBOSS 4

Tags: web-services, jboss, jax-ws

I need to deploy CXF-JAX WS Web Service in JBOSS version 4.x.

I tried deploy the example in http://united-coders.com/phillip-steffensen/developing-a-simple-soap-webservice-using-spring-301-and-apache-cxf-226/

In glassfish the web service getting published I can see the WSDL. But in JBOSS 4.x version it says 'There are currently no endpoints deployed" under

**localhost:8080/jbossws/services.**

Can you please let me know what am I missing ? how can I troubleshoot this further ?

When starting up the JBOSS server I can see below in my server.log

## Server log

```
06:35:59.233 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Apr 02 06:35:59 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
06:35:59.334 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-context.xml]
06:35:59.402 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
06:35:59.450 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]
06:35:59.469 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]
06:35:59.829 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@23ac5c8b: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationListener,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.resource.ResourceManager,org.apache.cxf.configuration.Configurer,org.apache.cxf.binding.BindingFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.DestinationFactoryManager,org.apache.cxf.transport.ConduitInitiatorManager,org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager,org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseManager,org.apache.cxf.workqueue.WorkQueueManager,org.apache.cxf.buslifecycle.BusLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientLifeCycleManager,org.apache.cxf.transports.http.QueryHandlerRegistry,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.EndpointResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.headers.HeaderManager,org.apache.cxf.catalog.OASISCatalogManager,org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServiceContractResolverRegistry,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer,org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory,personServ,personService]; root of factory hierarchy
02/04/2015 6:36:01 AM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://demo.unitedcoders.com/}PersonServiceImplService from class com.unitedcoders.demo.PersonService
02/04/2015 6:36:01 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /personService
06:36:01.960 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2799 ms
02/04/2015 6:36:01 AM org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet updateContext
INFO: Load the bus with application context
06:36:01.975 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext] Refreshing org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext@6a469846: startup date [Thu Apr 02 06:36:01 EST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
06:36:02.045 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1f769f17: defining beans []; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@23ac5c8b
02/04/2015 6:36:02 AM org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet replaceDestinationFactory
INFO: Servlet transport factory already registered
```

Comment: Why are you looking for your webservice under localhost:8080/jbossws/services ? Isn't your service deployed at localhost:8080/<context-root>/personService?

Comment: No nothing is deployed. This is the behavior in JBOSS4. I saw somewhere it says Apache CXF is getting bundled internally in Jboss 7. Perhaps have to do JBOSS 4 Specific configurations.

Comment: This example works for me in JBOSS4 and JBOSS7 please give a try. Let me know if you want the sample code. https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/jaxwscxf_step1/#InstallCXF